# How to change active menu and submenu item style

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to change the colour of active menu/submenu which is selected by user.

For example when `Sub11` is clicked, `Link 1` and `Sub11` will both turn `red`. Likewise when `Sub22` is clicked, `Link 2` and `Sub22` will be `red`.

```css
ul a { cursor: pointer; }
.active { color:red;}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="active"><a>Link 1</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a>Sub11</a></li>
         <li><a>Sub12</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>Link 2</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a>Sub21</a></li>
         <li><a>Sub22</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where's your code?

Comment: you mean whole code?

Comment: Anything that can help us help you fix your issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using jquery this code:

```
$('.link > a').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.submenu > li').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).parent('ul').prev('a').addClass('active');

});
```

Explanation:

The first part: whenever you click on `.link` item you remove every other active item and set the clicked one to active.

The second part: whenever you click on a submenu item you remove active state from the previous item and set it to the clicked submenu item and its predecessor `.link` item

You gonna have to add classes `link` and `submenu` to your html like this:

```
<ul>
 <li class="link">
     <a class="active">Link 1</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
         <li><a>Sub11</a></li>
         <li><a>Sub12</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="link">
     <a>Link 2</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
         <li><a>Sub21</a></li>
         <li><a>Sub22</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="link"><a>Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7edwopj1/1/)

Comment: without *Javascript is not possible. You cannot detect click event with simple css

Comment: and if you have constraints, you should mention it in the question

Comment: no constraints. i just wondered. because i've read about something like that it is possible with body classes. like: <body class = "<?php echo $page ?>">

Comment: sorry but i make a mistake while writing my code. i editted it. so can you help me again :(

Comment: where to help, you have another question?

Comment: my code is changed a bit. </li> codes were at wrong place.

Comment: I noticed that, but I didn't want to interfere. I updated my answer